# 'Star in Purple box' icon for downloaded apps while switching tabs using Alt + Tab

Tags: icons, elementary-project, horus

I installed Elementary OS 7.0 Horus and downloaded Chrome and Firefox browsers. 
Chrome - via dpkg after downloading the .deb file 
Firefox - via apt - snap downloaded and installed

Using **Alacarte** app, I set the icons for both the applications. 
I am able to see these app icons in the dock.

However, after opening the apps and switching between them using Alt + Tab, I see 'Star in Purple box' icons for both Chrome and Firefox. It becomes a bit difficult for me to identify the apps in this case.

Could someone please mention what could be going wrong and how to fix them?

Thanks, 
Praseo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using AppEditor for years, you can find it in AppCenter, and never had an issue with it. I believe it has been originally developed for elementaryOS, so maybe try it.