# Purple icon containing a star for Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA's show

Tags: desktop, java, android-studio

I have `Android Studio` and `IntelliJ Idea` installed, and their icons at both the `dock` and the `Applications Menu` seem to work just fine, however, when `Alt + Tab` they both have this default icon of a star with purple background.
I came across [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/30153/star-in-purple-box-icon-for-downloaded-apps-while-switching-tabs-using-alt-t) thread which suggested using `AppEditor`, but to no avail. I've even tried to set the icon to both the `png` and `svg` format bundled with `Android Studio` and even tried the default ones offered by `AppEditor`, but none seemed to have any effect whatsoever. I've also tried manually editing the desktop launcher config file, but it still didn't work.

Those default icons make windows blend in when alt-tabbing. Is there any way around it? Thanks